# Is there an open source "Data over Voice" library?

Tags: audio, modulation, software-implementation

I need to transfer data from A to B using audio as the medium, with a speaker at one end and a microphone at the other. Sometimes simply through the air, but it must also work through legacy phone lines and in environments where the bandwidth is low (phone lines using cables, old wireless networks such as 2G, etc).

This is more complex than simply connecting a traditional V.32 modem, due to the ways the audio could be compressed/limited by the phone infrastructure.

I've found several research papers that explain methods to do "Data over Voice", but no open source library I can use. Is there such an open source library?

Comment: Audio modems are pretty common but vary greatly depending on the requirements and conditions. The amount of data you can transfer varies by MANY orders of magnitude depending on speaker, microphone, acoustic path, noise levels, etc. I don't think there is a one-size-fits-all library

Comment: So, you identified the problem that different channels used for voice comms in this day and age might have very different impairments. Now, there's two possible ways forward: 1. you live with low data rate and use a robust, simplistic, hard-to-break waveform that works on the common denominator; or 2. you look for something that detects and adapts to the channel at hand, with different modes for different channels.

Comment: By the way, the "old phone lines" problem is easier to solve than the "communication through VoIP / NGN" problem, in practice, because that's what modems have been doing for decades. And modern modems (think: V.90 or even V.92) are definitely in the 2. category of solutions. They negotiate the largest common denominator of capabilities of both sides, then extensively sound the channel, then settle on a mode that will work and adjust equalizers and power settings as adequate.

Comment: Therefore, I think the first step here is to define a baseline functionality (read: data rate, reliability) that you need. From there stems how complicated the solution needs to be, and also, how specialized the software you're looking for :)

Comment: @MarcusMüller Thanks Marcus. I was hoping for 10 kbit/s and that it would work on most common phone systems, but after reading a few research papers I've realized that this is too much to hope for. Perhaps a more modest 1 kbit/s would be realistic. Here is a paper that describes the problem well: https://arxiv.org/pdf/2102.10869v1.pdf

Comment: Yeah! I obviously haven't read that paper (yet, don't know when I'll manage), but the basic idea of using a codebook that typical vocoders will en- and decode with little loss is what I'd expect if you need to work through digital voice channels. You could do a simple experiment:

Comment: Get a low-complexity (i.e., old and bad) voice coder – like the GSM 06.10 linear predictor-based codec; there's a very established [FOSS library for it](https://quut.com/gsm/). Encode (`gsm_encode`) a dummy (silent? real voice?) signal into a GSM frame and `gsm_explode` the resulting data so you get the individual coefficients in an array. (keep the result around as template) Modify these coefficients (i.e., put your data symbols into that), `gsm_implode`, then `gsm_decode` to get audio samples back. If the coefficient choice you made is realistic for voice, you get something transmittable.

Comment: Now, in theory, doing `gsm_encode` and `gsm_explode` on that audio again would give you your original coefficients. (try! you might need to try a few different delays first)
Then, you guess it, you go and apply all the annoying channels you have in mind to these audio samples. With the noisy, distorted audio, you go and do the same `gsm_decode`, `gsm_explode` again. You'd noisy coefficients, and now you have a classical estimation problem of finding good symbols that remain easily distinguishable even under the adverse channel.